# React Places Autocomplete: Detect Clicks outside of suggestions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am using React Places Autocomplete to generate location suggestions. I want to force user to select one of the suggested locations, so I am trying to detect the clicks outside the elements generated here:

```
<div ref={suggestionsContainerRef}>
              {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                const className = suggestion.active ? 'suggestion-item--active' : 'suggestion-item';
                // inline style for demonstration purpose
                const style = suggestion.active
                            ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer' }
                            : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer' };
                return (
                  <div {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, { className, style })}  >
                    <span >{suggestion.description}</span>
                  </div>
                )
              })}
            </div>
```

This is not working as expected. Even I click on one of the span elements generated, it considers the click outside of the div. Any help?

Full Code:

```
type LocationInputProps = {
    id: string
    label: string
    placeholder: string
}

const LocationInput = ({id, label, placeholder}: LocationInputProps) => {

  const [address, setAddress] = useState<string>('');
  const [lat, setLat] = useState<number>();
  const [lon, setLon] = useState<number>();
  const [selectedAddress, setSelectedAddress] = useState(false);
  const suggestionsContainerRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Add a click event listener to the document to detect clicks outside the suggestions container
    document.addEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick);

    return () => {
      // Remove the click event listener when the component unmounts
      document.removeEventListener('click', handleDocumentClick);
    };
  }, []);

  const handleDocumentClick = (event: MouseEvent) => {
    // Check if the click target is not within the suggestions container
    if (
      suggestionsContainerRef.current &&
      !suggestionsContainerRef.current.contains(event.target as Node)
      
    ) {
        console.log('click is not within container')

        setAddress(''); // Clear the input value
          
    } 
  };

  return(
    <PlacesAutocomplete
        value={address}
        onChange={(address) => {setAddress(address)}}
        onSelect={(address) => {
          geocodeByAddress(address)
            .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
            .then(latLng => {console.log('Success', latLng)
        setLat(latLng.lat);
        setLon(latLng.lng);
        setSelectedAddress(true);
    })
            .catch(error => {console.error('Error', error)
        setSelectedAddress(false)});
       
          setAddress(address);
          
        }}
        searchOptions={{componentRestrictions: {country: 'US'}}}
      >
        {({ getInputProps, suggestions, getSuggestionItemProps }) => (
          <div>
          
              <div className="grid w-9/12 items-center gap-1.5">
      <Label>{label}</Label>
      <Input  id={id} placeholder={placeholder} {...getInputProps({
                className: 'location-search-input'
              })}/>
    </div>
    
            <div ref={suggestionsContainerRef}>
              {suggestions.map(suggestion => {
                const className = suggestion.active ? 'suggestion-item--active' : 'suggestion-item';
                // inline style for demonstration purpose
                const style = suggestion.active
                            ? { backgroundColor: '#fafafa', cursor: 'pointer' }
                            : { backgroundColor: '#ffffff', cursor: 'pointer' };
                return (
                  <div {...getSuggestionItemProps(suggestion, { className, style })}  >
                    <span >{suggestion.description}</span>
                  </div>
                )
              })}
            </div>
          </div>
        )}
      </PlacesAutocomplete>
  )
}

export default LocationInput
```

Comment: Could you try and give the ref to to the `div` that encloses the `span`

Comment: yup already tried that, it is not working either

Comment: I have created a minimally reproducible example and at first glance it works as expected. Could you please check it and tell me if I missed something. https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-meninsky-f66mw4?file=/src/App.js

You could also try to log actual container and childNodes and look at their DOM to make sure they are correct.

Comment: @DmitriyZhiganov thanks for the demo, your demo works when we have fixed number of suggesstions but the google places api dynamically changes the suggestions hence the suggestion div changes in every keystroke that is why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

One of the simplest way to detect outside click is by using **onBlur** event on the element on which you want to detect outside click.